# Rails: render .HEIC images in browser tranforming to jpg from Cloduinary using image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I'm currently trying to display a HEIC image in the browser via Cloudinary. [According to the documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_manipulation#converting_to_another_image_format) one can change the format of the image to display as jpg, The documentation also states support for [conversion of .HEIC images](https://cloudinary.com/product_updates/heif_input_image_format_support). However, when I try to use the `fetch_format` option from Cloudinary the browser still not rendering the HEIC image as JPEG although the image is there. This is what I tried:

```
<%= image_tag post.image, :fetch_format=> 'jpg' , class: "card-home__img" %>
```

and also

```
<%= cl_image_tag(url_for(post.image), :format => :png ,:type => 'fetch', class: "card-home__img") %>
```

Without success, how can I render an image as jpg format from cloduinary?

althought the AnalyzeJob from ActiveStorage kicks in the file still uploads but is unable to render as jpg

```
Redirected to http://res.cloudinary.com/XXXXXXXXX/image/upload/xxxxxxxxxxxq3r4.HEIC
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 16.1ms | Allocations: 2588)
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [ac0d5880-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]   Cloudinary Storage (338.6ms) Downloaded file from key: kjpith3bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [ac0d5880-a243-4fef-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] Skipping image analysis because ImageMagick doesn't support the file
```

Comment: Could you please share a URL example that the cl_image_tag method produces for a HEIC you want returned as JPEG?

Comment: ```<img class="rounded" src="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fdb07f697309fe87b9ac7ad41148b1d6b6ccca90/IMG_7293.HEIC">```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Cloudinary URL this redirects to. In addition, could you try also using the `format` transformation as opposed to `fetch_format`? Does that give the same result?

Comment: format didn't work either

Comment: Can you please share the URL of the image from Cloudinary?

Comment: https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/v1584732132/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.heic

Comment: The result should be: https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/v1584732132/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.jpg                However, when you convert this image to a png file it became larger than your limits (11MB) so fetch_format:jpg should work: https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/f_jpg/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.heic

Comment: so what do I need to modify?

Comment: @ShirlyManor that didn't work :( how can I redirect to the JPG url?

Comment: @StevenAguilar have you looked at the derived images? you should see the jpg image there. If you can't find it please send us ticket at support@cloudinary.com.